# Showing $Q_n = \frac{T_n(x)}{2^{n-1}}$ is the monic polynomial of least norm

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

> The Chebyschev polynomials are denoted by $T_n(x) = \cos (n\arccos x)$
>   and are orthogonal in relation to $\langle f,g\rangle =
>  \int_{-1}^1\frac{f(x)g(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$
>
> Show that $T_n(x) = \frac{(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^n+(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})^n}{2}$
>   and that $Q_n = \frac{T_n(x)}{2^{n-1}}$ is the monic polynomial of
>   smallest norm uniform in $[-1,1]$

I've found that $T_n(x) = \frac{(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^n+(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})^n}{2}$ here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2800290/166180

Now I'm trying to prove it's the polynomial of smallest norm. I think the norm should be derived from $\sqrt{\langle f,  f\rangle^2}$, so I should analyze

$$||Q_n||=\sqrt{\int_{-1}^1\frac{\left(\frac{T_n(x)}{2^{n-1}}\right)^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx}$$

but it looks too ugly and I don't know where to begin with.

Comment: I don't understand; you give a whole sequence of polynomials (one for each $n$). How then can *'it'* be the monic polynomial of smallest norm? What is *'it'* here?

Comment: Can you prove $Q_n$ is a monic polynomial? Also, are you sure which norm is being used?

Comment: @Somos I'm sure about the inner product, not the norm, it's just a guess. About the first question, I don't know how, because for $n=2$ the thing looks at least squared to me

Comment: The wikipedia article on [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) states "The Chebyshev polynomials Tn are polynomials with the largest possible leading coefficient, but subject to the condition that their absolute value on the interval [−1,1] is bounded by 1. They are also the extremal polynomials for many other properties.[2" see also the "Minimal $\infty$-norm" section.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: The word *"uniform"* means that the norm to be minimized is $\| f \| = \sup _{x \in [-1,1]} |f(x)|$. A [proof sketch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Minimal_%E2%88%9E-norm) has already been suggested by **Somos**, no need for bounty here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

Let us consider [Chebyshev Polynomial of the First Kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html).

Firstly, recurrence relation
$$T_{n+1}(x) = 2xT_n(x)-T_{n-1}(x),\tag1$$
where
$$T_0(x)=1,\quad T_1(x) = x,\tag2$$
provides that the polynomials $Q_n(x)$ are monic, if $n>0$.

So should be
$$Q_0=1.$$

Secondly, one can prove the orthogonality in the form of
$$\int\limits_{-1}^1\dfrac{T_m(x)T_n(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx 
= \int\limits_{-1}^1 \cos(m\arccos x)\cos(n\arccos x)\,d(arccos x)$$
$$=\int\limits_{-\large\frac\pi2}^{\large\frac\pi2}\cos mt\cos nt \,dt
=\dfrac12\int\limits_{-\large\frac\pi2}^{\large\frac\pi2}\left(\cos(m+n)t+\cos (m-n)t\right) \,dt$$
$$=\begin{cases}
\pi,\quad\text{if}\quad m=n=0\\
\frac12,\quad\text{if}\quad m=n\not =0\\
0,\quad\text{if}\quad m\not=n.\\
\end{cases}$$
Thus, polynomials $\{Q_n(x)\}$ also are orthogonal.

On the other hand, the arbitrary $n$-th order monic $P_n(x)$ allows decomposition in the form of
$$P_n(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} c_k Q_k(n),\quad\text{where}\quad c_n=1.$$
Therefore,
$$\|P_n(x)\|^2 = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} c_k^2\int\limits_{-1}^1\dfrac{Q_k^2(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx+\sum\limits_{1\le i<j\le n}2^{i+j-1}c_ic_j \int\limits_{-1}^1\dfrac{T_i(x)T_j(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$$
$$ = \|Q_n(x)\|^2 + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} c_k^2\|Q_k(x)\|^2 > \|Q_n(x)\|^2, \quad\text{if}\quad P_n(x)\not = Q_n(x).$$

Comment: First, on the very last line it should be $Q_n$ instead of $Q_k$. Second, you are showing the minimality of the norm of $Q_n$ in the $L^2$-norm, when in reality you were supposed to show it in the *uniform convergence norm* (check the question once more, carefully, and then my comment under it). The OP, not understanding a thing, has rushed to accept the answer...

Comment: @AlexM.Thank you for a serious attention, you are right. As I feel the situation, OP did not need in the detalized sollution, only in the plan. At the same time, your comment is actual even in this case.

Comment: Why can you pass the $||.||$ into the sum?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Thank you for the comment. Detalized.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by $d( \arccos x)$?

Comment: why $P_n(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} c_k Q_k(n),\quad\text{where}\quad c_n=1$?