# Chebyshev Polynomial of degree 3

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, numerical-methods, chebyshev-polynomials

This is the question:

(a) Given a function $f(x)=e^{-(a+1)x}$. Find the polynomial of degree $2$ , $p_{2}(x)$ such that (with $w(x)=1$):

$$||f-p_{2}||_{L^{2}(0,1)}=\min_{q \in P_{2}(0,1)}||f-q||_{L^{2}(0,1)}.$$

(b) Find the polynomial of degree $3$, $q_{3}(x)$ in $[-1,1]$

$$||q_{3}(x)||_{L^{\infty}(-1,1)}\leq ||x^3 -(\alpha + \beta)x -2||_{L^{\infty}(-1,1)}$$

I solved (a). I want some help solving (b). Someone from the community told me it has to do with the Chebyshev polynomials and is probably right about that. But i can't find a formal way to do (b).

Proof:

$$r(x)=x^{n+1}-q_{n}(x),~~~q_{n}(x) \in P_{n}[a,b]$$

We have that

$$P_{n+1}^1=\{r \in P_{n+1}[a,b]/r(x)=x^{n+1}-q_{n}(x),~q_{n}(x) \in P_{n}[a,b]\}$$

$$\min_{r \in P_{n+1}^1}||r||_{\infty}=\min_{q_{n} \in P_{n}[a,b]}||x^{n+1}-q_{n}(x)||_{\infty}=||x^{n+1}-(x^{n+1}-2^{-n}T_{n+1})||_{\infty}=\frac{1}{2^{n}}||T_{n+1}||_{\infty}$$

So here i proved that from all the monic polynomials of degree $n+1$ the $ 2^{-n}T_{n+1}(x)$ has the smallest $L^{\infty}$-norm on [-1,1].

Comment: b) is still incomprehensible. Is not  $q_3(x)=x^3-4x-2$ at least admissible, or even a solution? The right side as it is is just a complicated way to write the number $5$, so $q_3$ can be any polynomial that has $5$ as a sharp bound on the interval $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Yeah since : $$\sup_{x \in (-1,1)}(x^2-4x-2)=5$$. Then its right to say that any polynomial of degree 3 that has $$\sup_{x \in (-1,1)}(q_{3}(x)) \leq 5$$ satisfies the inequality ?

Comment: Yes, if you think of the parentheses as vertical strokes for the absolute value. But that feels incomplete, the stated topic was Chebyshev, least max-error approximation. Approximating a cubic polynomial with a cubic polynomial has the obvious solution, so where is the difficulty of the task?

Comment: The inequality was: $$||q_{3}(x)||_{L^{\infty}(-1,1)}\leq ||x^3 -(\alpha+\beta)x -2||_{L^{\infty}(-1,1)}$$  for arbitrary choice of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. And i am trying to understand why the chebyshev polynomial of degree 3 satisfies the inequality for arbitrary choice of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: You are talking about $q_3(x)=\cos(3\arccos(x))$? And the claim is that the smallest value of the right side for any $α$ and $β$ is still larger than the fixed value $1$ on the left?

Comment: Yes exactly that! I am trying to see if that inequality holds for any $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: Nice work, @Luck-e.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for telling me @amWhy !

Comment: You are guessing. Read again on the whole topic, what the Chebyshev polynomials are, what connection they have to approximating $x^n$ with polynomials of a lower degree, what the minimality condition for uniform approximation is.

Comment: @Lutz Lehman Is there something wrong with proof I did ?

Comment: I do not see anything that is right with this proof. The accumulation of symbols is mostly syntactically correct, but what is $P_{n+1}[a,b]/r(x)$? What you seem to express appears to be a circular argument, you need to express more clearly what is assumed to be known for this proof. The proof should either reduce to a one-liner that the right side polynomial is not Chebyshev, thus automatically has larger norm, or, if that can not be used, needs to contain explicit norm computations.

Comment: $P_{n+1}^1$ are the polynomials with degree of $n+1$ which the leading coefficient is equal to $1$. So $r(x) \in P_{n+1}^1$ can be writen as $r(x)=x^{n+1}-q_{n}(x),~~q \in P_{n}(x)$

Comment: I'll look at the theory again and i will try to come up with the proof. I found this proof for the thing i tried to prove: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190309/showing-q-n-fract-nx2n-1-is-the-monic-polynomial-of-least-norm